# Extraer la primer linea de un párrafo (Unix) cut o awk

Tags: unix, awk, cut

Cita en bloque

Necesito extraer cada línea que empiece con '>' de un archivo y hacer uno nuevo con lo extraido.

Ejemplo:

```
>WP_013682727.1 hypothetical protein [Archaeoglobus veneficus]
    MLGGEKSEKTAKQSFLEDFVDEGGLFDEPADSDFSMLLNDTVEIGGLHYNDLARIQREWCKNRHWKLVEFTPASDGYHFI
    AVLKMTTRHPLKKLRVRLMRALREKSIAREQLIELLDEHAFVDEVLEIKGVVQ

>WP_013682728.1 hypothetical protein [Archaeoglobus veneficus]
MKCERCSIENTLRKALGEFRGSKIAIYDIDYLVEIEKRIVNMTEEKKLRKNGRRLLPAFEAVPALRIARVFGSDYTVLFS
DAKNDYYELYKLERTPLYVKYIDLQIYGELIVAGDLGDLRKAYFDLYFKDYYKKHRDDLMKLDTDLVLSVI
```

Estoy en terminal de Linux y lo he intentado con cut y awk, corto lo que  necesito pero no puedo guardarlo en otro archivo.

con cut:

```
cut -d ">" -f14 GCF_000194625.1_ASM19462v1_protein.faa
```

con awk:

```
awk -F ">" '{print $1}' GCF_000194625.1_ASM19462v1_protein.faa > id.t
```

Comment: es decir, ¿el fichero tiene muchas líneas y quieres copiar a otro archivo todas aquellas que empiezan por ">"? El código `cut -d ">" -f14` hace otra cosa, por lo que iría bien que mostraras cómo debe ser la salida

Comment: ¿Por qué no usas grep?. `grep "^>" archivo`

Comment: Podrías poner un ejemplo con el primer párrafo? Cómo se llamaría *exactamente* el fichero resultante? Y cuál es el contenido exacto que tendría ese fichero resultante?

Answer (score 0):

Con awk es muy sencillo:

Primeramente, en `awk` puedes utilizar patrones `//` con expresiones regulares `^>` para ejecutar la órden de imprimir la linea siempre que sea Inicio de línea (en el patrón es el `^`)  y luego el `>`

```
awk '/^>/' file.dat 
>WP_013682727.1 hypothetical protein [Archaeoglobus veneficus]
>WP_013682728.1 hypothetical protein [Archaeoglobus veneficus]
```

Así, ya conseguimos imprimir las líneas.

Si ahora necesitas imprimir cada una de esas lineas en un fichero diferente, lo único que necesitamos es redirigir la salida con un `>`

```
awk '/^>/ {print $0 > "ficheroSalida.dat"}' file.dat
$ cat ficheroSalida.dat
>WP_013682727.1 hypothetical protein [Archaeoglobus veneficus]
>WP_013682728.1 hypothetical protein [Archaeoglobus veneficus]
```

Ahora, ya que quieres crear un fichero para cada una de las lineas, al mirar la línea que propones, veo que podemos considerar la primera parte como válida para generar el nombre del fichero (WP_013682727 por ejemplo). Eso significa, que si dividimos por el punto, podremos obtener de ahí el nombre del fichero. Añadiremos entonces el `-F"."` para decirle a awk que divida por el punto, y llamaremos al fichero como el campo `$1` que será siempre el primero de la linea, es decir, `WP_013682727`

Observa que en este caso utilzo `gsub` para poder eliminar el `>` al principio del nombre del fichero que creo, y poder imprimir un nombre más correcto;

```
awk -F"." '/^>/ {gsub(/>/, "", $1); file=$1".dat";  print $0 > file }' file.dat
$ ls
$ cat WP_013682727.dat
>WP_013682727.1 hypothetical protein [Archaeoglobus veneficus]
```

Por tanto, ya tenemos al menos las líneas que empiezan por `>` en cada fichero con su nombre referente a la linea.

Ahora sólo nos quedaría imprimir las lineas que no contienen el `>` al principio en el fichero que hemos ido creando. Para eso utilizamos la negación `!` en el patrón de antes: `!/^>/`. En este caso, debemos concatenar al fichero en vez de crearlo, por lo que utilizamos la doble redirección `>>`

```
awk -F"." '/^>/ {file=$1".dat";gsub(/>/, "", file);  print $0 > file } !/^>/ { print $0 >> file } ' file.dat
```

Así, todas las lineas que vengan después de una cabecera de tipo `>.....` se imprimirán en el fichero perteneciente a esa cabecera. En cuanto el script encuentre otra cabecera nueva, cambiará el nombre de fichero y seguirá igual imprimiendo.

El resultado final, es este:

```
$ cat WP_013682727.dat
>WP_013682727.1 hypothetical protein [Archaeoglobus veneficus]
    MLGGEKSEKTAKQSFLEDFVDEGGLFDEPADSDFSMLLNDTVEIGGLHYNDLARIQREWCKNRHWKLVEFTPASDGYHFI
    AVLKMTTRHPLKKLRVRLMRALREKSIAREQLIELLDEHAFVDEVLEIKGVVQ

$ cat WP_013682728.dat
>WP_013682728.1 hypothetical protein [Archaeoglobus veneficus]
MKCERCSIENTLRKALGEFRGSKIAIYDIDYLVEIEKRIVNMTEEKKLRKNGRRLLPAFEAVPALRIARVFGSDYTVLFS
DAKNDYYELYKLERTPLYVKYIDLQIYGELIVAGDLGDLRKAYFDLYFKDYYKKHRDDLMKLDTDLVLSVI
```

Espero que te ayude.

**EDIT:**

Viendo que parece que puede importarte el número que hay detrás del punto, únicamente con eliminar el `-F"."` , el mismo `awk` separará por el espacio por defecto, así que básicamente tendrás el nombre completo.

```
$ awk '/^>/ {file=$1".dat";gsub(/>/, "", file);  print $0 > file } !/^>/ { print $0 >> file } ' file.dat
$ ls
WP_013682727.1.dat  WP_013682728.1.dat  ficheroSalida.dat  file.dat
```